# Редактирование hosts с помощью C++

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые специалисты. Без лишних предисловий опишу то, что нужно. А нужно мне отредактировать файл hosts (drivers/etc) с помощью С++ посредством консольной программы. То есть, я пишу заданный текст, который оно заменит (перед этим делаю бекап файла), запускаю файл, а оно изменяет текст. Меня интересуют любые способы, но желательно более простые (студент-первокурсник, только-только начали учить программирование. Но хочется шагнуть немного вперед, так как скорость работы на парах вообще не удовлетворяет). Надеюсь на вашу помощь. В гугле смотрел, нашел несколько комманд, но не совсем понял, как их применять. Если можно, приведите небольшой пример.

**UPD:** Дополнительный вопрос. В андроиде (как я прочитал в вики) тоже есть этот файл. Скажите, он влияет на все приложения или только на браузер?

Comment: Ну и студенты пошли, какая-то каша в голове. Даже сформулировать вопрос не могут - просто адъ. Особенно умиляет:
>Скажите, он влияет на все приложения или только на браузер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fopen fread ... fwrite fflush fclose? 
но тут другой вопрос - сейчас антивирусы начали модно бороться с внесением изменений в данный файл. блокируют на запись, восстанавливают дефолтные настройки и т.д. т.е. стоит учитывать данный факт, при реализации софтины.

**upd**. простой пример:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE *fh;
    char *path;
    char *data = "\t127.0.0.1 localhost\n\t127.0.0.1 test.com\n"; //то что пишем в файл hosts

    path = (char *)LocalAlloc(LPTR, MAX_PATH + 1); // выделяем память из локальной кучи, под строку содержащую путь с именем файла

    GetWindowsDirectoryA(path, MAX_PATH); // c:\Windows
    lstrcatA(path, "\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts"); // добавляем путь с именем файла. в результате в строке: c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

    fh = fopen(path, "a+"); //открываем файл на чтение и добавление данных
    if(fh == NULL ){            
        printf( "The file %s was not opened\n", path ); 
        LocalFree(path);
        return 0;
    }
    fwrite(data, sizeof(char), lstrlenA(data), fh); // записываем данные в файл. 
    /*
        1й параметр - указатель на записываемые данные
        2й параметр - размер элемента в байтах
        3й параметр - максимальное число записываемых элементов
        4й параметр - указатель на структуру типа FILE
    */
    fclose(fh); //закрываем файл

    LocalFree(path); //освобождаем ранее выделенную память.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: так тебе команды нужны? держи. из командной строки:
echo 127.0.0.1 localhost >> %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: нет, прошу прощения, неправильно выразился. fopen fread это функции? В общем, хотел узнать, как пользоваться именно ими? Ну или как с помощью С++ использовать командную строку?

Comment: нашел, что ч помощью С++ можно использовать консольные команды. Но почему-то оно у меня не работает. вот код:

int main()
{
return system ("echo 127.0.0.1 localhost >> %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts");
}

Comment: Попробовал, сначала не вышло, подключил ещё <tchar.h>. Компилируется нормально, но при запуске выдаёт такую штуку: http://piccy.info/view3/3462136/47d802fb15a78f0aab9e4468693a7305/

Comment: Символы `\` в тексте надо удваивать

    "%SYSTEMROOT%\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts"

Comment: @avp программа компилируется и работает нормально, но hosts остается прежним!

Comment: @Vendetta8247 у тебя точно не включен никакой антивирус?
ошибка из-за того что не открылся файл, а проверок небыло. тк. ты сказал что решил проблему с доступом к файлу hosts. если есть что-то типа касперского - оно блокирует доступ к данному файлу на запись.

Comment: @Vendetta8247, программа и будет компилироваться с неправильными слэшами, а вот файл не найдёт.

Comment: @Vendetta8247, не знаю, чем Вы компилоруете, а gcc пишет Warnings. Получившийся из 

    "echo 127.0.0.1 localhost >> %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

код пытается выполнить

    echo 127.0.0.1 localhost >> %SYSTEMROOT%System32drivers?tchosts

Реально вместо `?` выводится код 033 (escape)